# rhel 6.4 pip with proxy error : name or service not known

Tags: proxy, python, rhel6, pip

the pip command

```
pip search statsd --proxy=http://anadi.misra:XXXXXXXXX@192.168.200.77:8080
```

Now my password contains an @ too so I give the encoded form in password; i.e.

some@pass is supplied as some%40pass, but I get exception name or service not known which makes me feel there is still some syntax issue here, the exception log:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 38, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, index_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 52, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1235, in request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1349, in send_content
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 908, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 780, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 739, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 720, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

The same proxy configuration works for yum in /etc/yum.conf though